# Load kernel module prior of device tree's probing

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, device-tree

I have developed a working driver for my *custom_hardware* that relies on the device tree. Because my driver may evolve, I do not want my driver to be part of the kernel (when I say 'be part of the kernel', I mean, to be compiled with the kernel during the kernel creation)

Here is a glimpse of my dts:

```
custom_hardware: custom_hardware@0x41006000 {
    compatible = "mfg,custom";
    reg = <0x41006000 0x1000>;
    #interrupt-cells = <0x1>;
    interrupt-controller;
};

existing_hardware: existing_hardward@41004000 {
    compatible = "mfg,existing";
    reg = <0x41004000 0x1000>;
    interrupt-parent = <&custom_hardware>;
    interrupts = <0>;
};
```

The *existing_hardware*'s driver is already compiled with kernel (the *existing_hardware*'s driver has been compiled with the kernel during the kernel creation).

What I would like to do is to append my *custom_hardware*'s driver to the ramfs and let the kernel loads the  *custom_hardware*'s driver prior of the *existing_hardware*'s driver.

This is important since the *existing_hardware*'s driver requests a *virq* from the *irq_domain* of the *custom_hardware*'s driver. In order to get the *irq_domain*, the *custom_hardware*'s driver must be loaded first.

Note that the *existing_hardware*'s driver gets loaded during the probing of the device tree which seems to happen in the early stage of the kernel booting sequence.

Comment: You seem to be overstating the requirements. *" I do not want my driver to be part of the kernel."* *"Load kernel module prior (to) device tree probe."*  Seems like the only salient requirement is that the *custom_hardware* driver needs to be installed before the *existing_hardware* driver, which can be accomplished within the existing framework. See this **[Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541290/what-is-the-difference-between-module-init-and-subsys-initcall-while-initializin/15542788#15542788)**

Answer (score 2):

That is not the way to do. The order of the module/driver loading must not matter. What you need to do is return `-EPROBE_DEFER` when getting the IRQ fails in existing_hardware. Then it will get probed again at a later time, hopefully after custom_hardware got probed.

Also, you can apply that patch that will ensure that `request_irq()` fails because the domain is not present yet and return `-EPROBE_DEFER` in that case
https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/2/13/114

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem (probing order was wrong) and the only simple solution what I found is put the modules in the desired probing order into the Makefile.
I've found the solution here: [What is the Linux built-in driver load order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642330/linux-built-in-driver-load-order)